# Oracle NoSQL { Error: socket hang up } when running nodejs

Tags: node.js, oracle-nosql

**$ java -Xmx256m -Xms256m -jar $KVHOME/lib/kvstore.jar ping -port 5000 -host node01**

I can able to ping and get information with this command

But when i run tried to run example(quickstart.js) code from oracle-nosqldb github page, I'm getting error like

**Error: [REQUEST_TIMEOUT] Operation timed out after 10000 ms and 6 retries; Caused by: [NETWORK_ERROR] Network error; Caused by: socket hang up
from:
tableDDL**

What exactly this error means, can anyone help me with this

Comment: Did you start the HTTP proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The node.js SDK requires the httpproxy to be running. Based on your [additional question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71522432/error-running-oracle-nosql-httpproxy-jar-gives-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror/71560707#71560707) you seem to have figured that out.

Look at the [proxy documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/20.3/admin/proxy.html) and the [node.js SDK documentation](https://oracle.github.io/nosql-node-sdk/tutorial-connect-on-prem.html) for more details

George