# Error running Oracle NoSQL httpproxy.jar gives "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, linux, database, oracle, oracle-nosql

while trying to run httpproxy for oracle nosql Database I'm facing an error like

```
**$ java -jar $KVHOME/lib/httpproxy.jar -storeName mystore -helperHosts localhost:5000 -hostname localhost -httpPort 8080**


**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/nosql/common/http/ProxyRequestHandler
    at oracle.nosql.proxy.Proxy.startServer(Proxy.java:277)
    at oracle.nosql.proxy.Proxy.start(Proxy.java:226)
    at oracle.nosql.proxy.Proxy.initialize(Proxy.java:172)
    at oracle.nosql.proxy.ProxyMain.startProxy(ProxyMain.java:160)
    at oracle.nosql.proxy.ProxyMain.main(ProxyMain.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.nosql.common.http.ProxyRequestHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 5 more**
```

can anyone help solving this issue

Comment: Can you provide information about your OS, and the version used? Please run `java -version`, `java -Xmx64m -Xms64m -jar $KVHOME/lib/kvstore.jar version` and `java -Xmx64m -Xms64m -jar $KVHOME/lib/kvclient.jar`

Answer (score 0):

You indicated you are using the 19.5 community edition. This release has a packaging issue that is causing your problem. You need to use the 20.3 community edition, which is the most recent CE that is available for download.